# Reverse list implementation and pointers understanding

Tags: java, pointers, nodes

Assume I have a class called Node:

```
public class Node {
    public Node next; 

    //etc......
}
```

and a class NodesList:

```
public class NodesList {
    public Node head;

    //etc.... 
}
```

Now I want to implement a function to reverse a list, like that:

```
public reverseList () {
    Node curr = head; 
    Node prev = null;

    while (curr != null){
       curr.next = prev;
       prev = curr;
       head = head.next;
       curr = head;
    }

    head = prev;
 }
```

My question is pretty basic: I assigned ***curr = head***.

Why, in the assignment ***curr.next = prev,*** it doesn't change the **head** also to  ***head.next = prev*** and ruin the list?

And where can I read about it to understand more what happen behind the scenes?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: This looks like something you can explore in your favourite debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curr` and `head` point to the first node initially. When you do `curr.next = prev`, both `curr.next` and `head.next` are `null`. There is no way for you to reverse the list now as the connection between the first node and the rest of the list is lost. Now when the `head = head.next` statement executes, your `head` will point to `null` and that means that there is no starting point for the list.

One thing to remember is to never use the `head` pointer for moving across the nodes in a list. `head` should be made to always point to the start of a list. In the case of reversing a list, `head` can be updated to point to the new start node of the list after reversing it.

One way to reverse a list would be:

```
Node prev = null;
Node curr = head;
Node next;

while (curr != NULL)
{
    next  = curr.next;  
    curr.next = prev;   
    prev = current;
    current = next;
}
head = prev;
```

In the above snippet, there is a pointer called `next` which will first point to `current`'s next node. So now after `curr.next = prev` is executed, curr can move to the next node in the list to be reversed via the statement `curr = next`. This ensures that the connectivity of the list is not lost.

After the while loop reverses the list, `prev` will be pointing to the new first node of the list. Now you can modify the `head` to point to this node.

Answer (score 0):

> Why, in the assignment `curr.next = prev`, it doesn't change the `head` also to `head.next = prev` and ruin the list?

But it does change `head.next` to `prev`. At the point that assignment, `curr` and `head` are references to the same object. This doesn't ruin the list because `head` gets set to other elements as you run through the loop.

If that sounds a bit confusing, read on.

> And where can I read about it to understand more what happen behind the scenes?

There's nothing going on behind the scenes, you just need to have the right view of what happens "before the scenes".

What's happening is that you are building a reverse list using the same nodes of the old list. Now, you're traversing the old list the only way you can, which is forward - from the old list's head to its tail, advancing via `.next`. But for the new list, this needs to be the end of the list, so whenever you see another element you're adding it *before the head* rather than *after the tail* of your under-construction list.

So if you had:

```
(head) -> [node 1] -> [node 2] -> [node 3]
```

you're transforming it into:

```
null <- [node 1] <- (head)                        [node 2] -> [node 3] -> null

null <- [node 1] <- [node 2] <- (head)            [node 3] -> null

null <- [node 1] <- [node 2] <- [node 3] <- (head)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reasoning about what points to what, it's much simpler to reason about pop and push operations. In pseudocode, you can reverse `lst` onto `rvs` like this:

```
rvs = null;
while (lst != null) {
  Node tmp = pop(lst);
  rvs = push(rvs, tmp);
}
// rvs now contains the reversed list
```

Now all we need to do is replace `pop` and `push` with their implementations:

```
rvs = null;
while (lst != null) {
  // pop from lst
  Node tmp = lst;
  lst = lst.next;
  // push onto rvs
  tmp.next = rvs;
  rvs = tmp;
}
```